# C++ Member variable initialization in templated inherited class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to figure out whats wrong with this piece of code. Basically `type2` inherits from `type1<T>, type1<T2>` and I want to initialize the `value` member from one of the base classes.

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct type1 {
    using base_type = T;

    template <typename... Args> type1(Args&&... args) : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T value;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct type2 : public Ts... {
    template <typename T>
    type2(T&& arg) : T::value(std::move(arg.value)) {}
};

int main()
{
    type2<type1<int>, type1<double>> x(type1<int>(10));
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error from clang:

```
    Error(s):

source_file.cpp:15:25: error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'value' in 'type1<int>'
    type2(T&& arg) : T::value(std::move(arg.value)) {}
                        ^~~~~
source_file.cpp:20:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'type2<type1<int>, type1<double> >::type2<type1<int> >' requested here
    type2<type1<int>, type1<double>> x(type1<int>(10));
                                     ^
source_file.cpp:9:7: note: referenced member 'value' is declared here
    T value;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Why is clang saying `typename specifier refers to non-type member 'value' in 'type1<int>'`? Gcc wants to treat (probably clang too) `value` as a type:

```
Error(s):

source_file.cpp: In instantiation of ‘type2<Ts>::type2(T&&) [with T = type1<int>; Ts = {type1<int>, type1<double>}]’:
source_file.cpp:20:54:   required from here
source_file.cpp:15:51: error: no type named ‘value’ in ‘struct type1<int>’
     type2(T&& arg) : T::value(std::move(arg.value)) {}
                                                   ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a member of base class in the constructor initializer list.

In Standardese, `T::value(std::move(arg.value))` in `type2(T&& arg) : T::value(std::move(arg.value)) {}` is called a *mem-initializer*, and `T::value` is called a *mem-initializer-id*. According to [[class.base.init]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#2),

> Unless the *mem-initializer-id* names the constructor's class, a non-static data member of the constructor's class, or a direct or virtual base of that class, the *mem-initializer* is ill-formed.

You can call the constructor of the base class, and let it initialize the member. In this specific case, you only need to change `T::value(std::move(arg.value))` to `T(std::move(arg.value))`. [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qUklNvLAe2bPqEi2).